# Is $f(x)$ a value or a function?

Tags: functions, notation

I've seen it written 'the function $f(x)$', is it not the function $f$ and $f(x)$ is it's value at $x$ e.g. for some number $x$ there exists a value $f(x)$ depending on $x$?

I also see used to describe that 'the function $f(x)$ allows us to know the value $f(a)$ for any $a$' Again, surely the value is $f(x)$ and we can determine $f(x)$ for any $x$ in the domain, and this is the same? A textbook I have uses this language and also describing $a$ as a constant? Surely if we say 'for any $a$' we are allowing $a$ to change in this context as the 'for any' is a universal quantifier over the domain?

Comment: Saying that "the function $f(x)$" is sloppy but is used often. The function is $f$ and $f(x)$ is its value at $x$.

Comment: People use that expression a bit casually.  Sometimes it denotes the function, other times the value of the function at $x$.  Context ought to make it clear which is intended.  Note:  writing "we can determine $f(x)$ for any $x$" seems awfully strong.  It's easy to produce examples of functions for which some particular value is beyond our ability to compute.

Comment: @lulu are you saying defined functions on a point can be hard to compute? what do you mean by beyond our ability to compute?

Comment: let me rephrase that as 'there exists f(x) for any $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Where there are different variables about $f(x)$ can be used to emphasise the functional dependence on a particular variable of interest. Essentially, this usage is so common that you will need to get used to it. It is occasionally useful to know that a finer distinction has to be made.

Comment: Consider the function on the reals given by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\not \in \mathbb Q$.  We can't compute $f(e+\pi)$, for example.  And so on.  Any unsolvable problem could be coded as the value of a function.  Being able to compute values of a function should not be linked to the notion of "function".

Comment: @lulu ah I see what you mean. I interpret functions as a look up table anyway, but I never though of this example. Nice!